# Unable to delete build dir after running Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs

I am using the SonarQube Gradle plugin version 3.0 with Gradle 6.7.1 for analysis of my Java code. This works fine and the results are uploaded to Sonar. When I do `gradlew clean test sonarqube` initially I have no problem. But when I run it subsequently I get the following:

> ```
> java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory 'C:\xxx\build'
>
> Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has
> files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
>
> - C:\xxx\build\sonar\findbugs\findsecbugs-plugin.jar
> - C:\xxx\build\sonar\findbugs
> - C:\xxx\build\sonar
> ```

This keep on failing until I kill the Gradle daemon after which I can successfully run sonarqube again.
Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I have upgraded to SonarQube Gradle plugin 3.1 and Gradle 6.8, but this has not resolved the issue